# How can you use inner classes in static context?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to use inner classes to create a hierarchy of objects to avoid cluttering the API of my current project. The basic idea is to use something like this:

```
package foo {
    public class Bar {
        public static const BLUBB:Blubb = new Blubb();
        public static const ZONK:Zonk = new Zonk();
    }
}
class Blubb {
    public const GNARF:Gnarf = new Gnarf();
    public const BLUBB_BLAH:String = "blubb-blah";
}
class Gnarf {
    public const GNARF_BLAH:String = "gnarf-blah";
}
class Zonk {
    public const ZONK_BLAH:String = "zonk-blah";
}
```

so that I can use it like `someFunction(Bar.BLUBB.GNARF.GNARF_BLAH);`

However, apparently Actionscript doesn't quite like this construct (although FDT5 compiles it without giving a frell about it) and gives me the following runtime error:

```
Exception fault: TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
    at foo::Bar$cinit()
    at global$init()
    at ...
```

with the rest of the stacktrace leading to the point where I first tried to access any of the static constants of `Bar`.

Is it really not possible to use inner classes in such a way or am I just missing some secret voodoo?

Comment: My guess is the secret voodoo involved is a [static initializer](http://manishjethani.com/archives/2008/03/31/static-initializers-in-as3), but I haven't made it work yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to get this to work as you wanted, but I found some potentially useful things:

```
package foo {
    public class Bar {
        public const BLUBB:Blubb = new Blubb();
        public const ZONK:Zonk = new Zonk();
    }
}
class Gnarf {
    public const GNARF_BLAH:String = "gnarf-blah";
}
class Blubb {
    public static const GNARF:Gnarf = new Gnarf();
    public const BLUBB_BLAH:String = "blubb-blah";
}
class Zonk {
    public const ZONK_BLAH:String = "zonk-blah";
}
```

I had to take out the static modifiers for Bar's variables, but I found that I could add "static" to Blubb.GNARF *as long as* Gnarf was defined above Blubb. Based on this, I tried moving all three internal classes above the package definition, but it turns out that isn't allowed. (Also, you can't directly access internal classes from another file, so having a static variable in one of them isn't itself useful.)

I also tried making Bar.BLUBB a static var and initializing it in the static initialization block rather than inline, but that made no difference. I think if you want to use a certain class type for a static variable, you have to define that class type in a separate file.

Comment: I've been messing around a bit more with the problem, following your suggestions and hits and came to the result that I can't do what I want the way I want. So for the sake of a clean API I took all inner classes from their original files, put them each in seperate class files and stuffed them in a package I hope to never look into again. ^^